# Use OpenCV library in CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, opencv, codeblocks

I am using Codeblocks 16.01 with OpenCV 3.2.0-vc14 which is installed to C:\opencv
The compile and link search directory is set in CodeBlocks already.

I wrote an openCV example, and there's a conflict as following:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in try_opencv (compiler: openCL)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL_SDK\6.3\lib\x86" -LC:\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib -LC:\opencv\build\x64\vc14\bin -o bin\Debug\try_opencv.exe obj\Debug\main.o  -lOpenCL  C:\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib\opencv_world320.lib C:\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib\opencv_world320d.lib
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `main':
D:/TheOpenCLProgrammingBook/image_process_test/try_opencv/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
D:/TheOpenCLProgrammingBook/image_process_test/try_opencv/main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(cv::String const&, int)'
D:/TheOpenCLProgrammingBook/image_process_test/try_opencv/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
D:/TheOpenCLProgrammingBook/image_process_test/try_opencv/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `ZN2cv6StringC1EPKc':
C:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:622: undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned int)'
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `ZN2cv6StringD1Ev':
C:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:664: undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `ZN2cv3MatD1Ev':
C:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:592: undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `ZN2cv3MataSERKS0_':
C:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:613: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)'
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv':
C:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:704: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
10 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

It's so confused. Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to link libraries, e.g.

```
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib\opencv_world320.lib
```

that have been built with the MS Visual Studio 2014 C++ compiler in a program
that you are building with a different C++ compiler, namely `mingw32-g++`.

That won't work. Libraries built by one C++ compiler are in general
binary incompatible with programs or libraries built with a different
one and in particular, code built with an MS C++ compiler is binary
incompatible with code built by a GCC compiler (which you are using).

In addition, it seems that you are building a 32-bit program
with `mingw32-g++` - since the 32-bit TDM GCC compiler is the bundled
default compiler in Code::Blocks 16.01 - and are attempting to link
64-bit libraries with it. Even if the libraries were not made by
an incompatible compiler, you cannot link 64-bit code with 32-bit
code.

All the libraries that you link in your 32[64]-bit program must
have been built with the same compiler or at least a binary ABI compatible
compiler, and they must also be 32[64]-bit.

Start again and build OpenCV from source, for targeting mingw, 32-bit,
using your mingw32 compiler. Get the windows source in the zip archive [Source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/3.2.0.zip) 
from [the GitHub OpenCV repo](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases/tag/3.2.0).
It seems as if you may already have built from source. If so, then you
built the libraries for 64-bit VC++14, not mingw32, and those libraries
are useless.

To build the libraries again and configure an OpenCV project in Code::Blocks,
follow [this tutorial](http://kevinhughes.ca/tutorials/opencv-install-on-windows-with-codeblocks-and-mingw),
carefully.

Comment: I got it! Thank you Mike.